# What is the use of colon in function or variable in matlab.?

Tags: matlab

% Select the region of interest from the original video

```
OutIm = Im(roi(2):end, roi(1):end, :);
YCbCr = step(hColorConv, OutIm);
CbCr = complex(YCbCr(:,:,2), YCbCr(:,:,3));
```

What is use of : in the above code?

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](http://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/colon.html); it means 'all the elements' of the column or the row. More information in the [slicing section](http://nl.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/sliced-variables.html) of the documentation.

So basically, assuming `a` is a 2-dimensional array, `a(:,1)` refers to all the elements of the first column, while  `a(2,:)` refers to all the elements of the second line..

In your case, `YCbCr` is a 3-dimensional array, and `YCbCr(:,:,2)` to matrix of the second elements (`Cb`) and `YCbCr(:,:,3)` to the third element (`Cr`).